# Android - BroadcastReceiver never called from AlarmManager

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have a problem with my BroadcastReceiver. Basically, I have a function in my service, that I want to call every, let's say, 2 hours. So I used the AlarmManager and Broadcast receiver to do it, however, it looks like the receiver is never called. My code:

in service's onCreate method:

```
Intent intent5 = new Intent("MYINTENT");
sender2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 192838, intent5, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
am2 = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am2.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), 1000*60*60*2, sender2);

BroadcastReceiver connectionReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       check();
    }
  };

  registerReceiver(connectionReceiver, new IntentFilter("MYINTENT"));
```

and then there's the check() method

```
public static void check(){
    //some code
}
```

I've also tried to creat a class extending BroadcastReceiver, registering it in the Manifest etc, and it got called, but then I got a NullPointerException calling the service's check() metheod from within the BroadcastReceiver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've also tried to creat a class extending BroadcastReceiver, registering it in the Manifest etc, and it got called, but then I got a NullPointerException calling the service's check() metheod from within the BroadcastReceiver.

Go back to that solution, then fix your `NullPointerException`. Most likely, Android terminated the process of your app that called `registerReceiver()` (e.g., user pressed HOME and did not return to the process). `check()` -- whatever that is -- has to assume that this is a brand-new process. Your `NullPointerException` probably comes from `check()` thinking that something should be initialized, when it is not.

Comment: Yeah, that actually was a better solution indeed. When I finally found the cause of that exception, it worked like a charm. Thanks!